# Add user in CaseTeamTemplate but not showing in Case Related list

Tags: service, salesforce, case

I have a case and its related list that displays the case team assigned to it. However, I've noticed an issue: when there are initially three users in the case team, the related list only shows those three users. If I add another user to the case team using the Salesforce org, the added user doesn't appear in the case's related list for the case team. It continues to show the same three users. However, if I remove the case team from the case's related list and then re-add the same case team, it correctly displays the updated information, including the added user, totaling four users. I need a solution as it should show the updated case team into case related list immeditaly.
I tried with trigger but we can not use trigger on the caseteamtemplate, caseteamtemplatemember, and caseteammember objects. Is there any way that can ensure that any modifications, such as adding or removing users, will be accurately reflected in the case team's related list without the need for manual intervention.